# vb.net abort thread without defining it

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, ping, abort

I'm working on a ping program, that has a series of ping targets, each spawns its own thread to ping on, to avoid slowing up the UI thread.

When the user edits the ping target's properties to change the time between pings(frequency), which is also how long the thread sleeps for, a new thread is created with the updated sleep time, the original thread keeps going though, the result is two threads pinging the same computer at varying times, which is why I need to end the original thread before I start a new one with updated parameters.

```
    'Set up a class as a ping object, it will store information necessary (not sure entirely how this works)
Class pingObj
    Property Name As String
    Property IP As String
    Property Frequency As String
    Property TimeOut As String
End Class

'Main ping sub, starts the threads to ping on!
Public Sub Ping(Name As String)

    Dim Parameters As New pingObj
    Parameters.Name = Name
    Parameters.IP = Targets(Name)(0)
    Parameters.Frequency = Targets(Name)(1)
    Parameters.TimeOut = Targets(Name)(2)


    Dim thread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf PingThread)
    thread.IsBackground = True
    thread.Start(Parameters)

End Sub

'The thread itself, pings each system to determine if it is offline or online.
Public Sub PingThread(p As Object)
    Dim Parameters As pingObj = DirectCast(p, pingObj)

    'Do stuff
    Do

        If Targets.ContainsKey(Parameters.Name) Then

            'Lots of ping code'

            'Delay based on the frequency set.
            Dim TimeInMS As Integer = TimeSpan.Parse(Parameters.Frequency).TotalMilliseconds
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeInMS)
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

Basically, above, I'm starting a thread with Ping(Name), gathering data about the ping target from my dictionaries, and using an object (pingobj) to shove that data into the PingThread() sub. Currently, when a target is deleted from the dictionary, the "if targets.containskey(parameters.name)" catches that it's gone and does the "Exit Do", which stops the function of the thread long enough that it automatically aborts itself:

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0x2314) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

However, when the user edits the properties of the target, and changes the Frequency (how long the thread sleeps for), I need to forcefully ABORT the original thread and start a new one with the new parameters, so that I don't have two threads pinging the same target more often than the user defined.

The difficult part is that the thread is created on the fly in the ping() sub, and the thread is not stored anywhere. So I can't just call thread.abort() when I need to, I can only abort the thread from inside the thread's sub PingThread().

TL;DR: I need a way to abort a thread that is created on the fly and not stored because the user changed how long the thread sleeps for.

P.S. Why can't I type a capital t? I have to copy paste one in order to use it.

Comment: Keep track of what you create 'on the fly'. But aborting a thread is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: What else can I do? I need the thread to stop pinging in order to make a new one, surely vb.net wasn't designed in a way that makes it horribly difficult and destructive to end threads, which are so necessary to have in the first place...

Comment: use a flag and check it from the thread, aborting a thread can stop it anywhere including in the middle of the ping code potentially leaving network classes in invalid state.

Comment: The problem is the use of the .Sleep.  Change it to a Threading.AutoResetEvent.WaitOne(timespan) which you can wake by setting.